# Unexpected value in openshift service discovery

Tags: microservices, openshift, service-discovery

I have a couple of microservices, deployed through S2I, on an openshift cluster. Each of them are exposed by service and route. The first microservice needs to communicate with the REST API of the other one (on another pod) through http. When I deploy the first microservice, I pass an environment variable MICROSERVICE_2_SERVICE_HOST with the value 'http://microservice-2' ('microservice-2' is the name of the generated openshift service of microservice 2, of type ClusterIP.. both generated services are of type ClusterIP)

Within the first microservice, I used the environment variable MICROSERVICE_2_SERVICE_HOST to build the URL of the REST API. The problem is that instead of getting 'http://172.30.245.8:8080/...' as one could expect in kubernetes, I'm getting 'tcp://172.30.245.8:8080/...' and the REST client cannot build the URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: tcp

When I check the environment variables within the container of the microservice 1 I see:
`MICROSERVICE_2_PORT=tcp://172.30.245.8:8080 MICROSERVICE_2_PORT_8080_TCP=tcp://172.30.245.8:8080 MICROSERVICE_2_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=172.30.245.8 MICROSERVICE_2_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080 MICROSERVICE_2_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO=tcp ...`

I have tried changing the services to NodePort but I get the same result. I know I could use the IP:port values inside the string but I'd like to know why and how openshift works

Comment: Did you set these environment variables? If yes then change them, if not, who or what did? Also, what openshift version are you running?

Comment: I set the variable in the DeploymentConfig when I create the app via s2i at the openshift webconsole. I could change the variable to just 'microservice-2' but the question is why openshift is putting tcp protocol. I'm using the red hat openshift sandbox so I guess is the last 4.x

Answer (score 0):

This is inlined with the [expected](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables) behaviour. I suppose you could use `MICROSERVICE_2_SERVICE_PORT` and `MICROSERVICE_2_SERVICE_HOST` to achieve the url composition.